# Spring @Cacheable using hset

Tags: java, spring, caching, redis

I am using spring and it's cache abstractions. It's very convenient to use the @Cacheable annotation.
But as far as I know this abstraction use get/set/del operations on redis.
Is there any way to use hset/hget/hdel?

Answer (score 0):

I done that using redisson RMAP and spring CacheResolver.